# Horizontal manager alignment of its child view?

Tags: android, android-layout

How can I align a child view in the horizontal LinearLayout?
I have two textviews (width height is wrap_content) in the horizontal manager. How I can align one to right and the other one to the left?

Comment: post your code please

Comment: Do you mean horizontal layout ?

Comment: I mean horizontal linearlayout

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing what you mean by "horizontal manager" it's really hard to answer your question. Do you mean a horizontal layout? Is this what you're looking for?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```